# Custom Vim syntax highlighting only works for some keywords

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting, neovim

I'm writing a custom syntax highlighting file for a proprietary language I have to use a lot.  I have written a full file but it seems to only use 3 colors.  All punctuation is one color, some of the keywords I have specified are another color, and everything else is a third color.

The odd thing is, I removed every match and every redefinition (hi def link) from the file and the highlighting doesn't seem to have changed at all.  In fact, I tried adding some other keyword mappings to try to see where it's breaking, but it seems only certain lines are being evaluated for the highlighting.  For instance, this line ends up highlighting the proper text:

```
syn keyword clangImport IMPORT
```

However, this line (below) doesn't and is a different color despite not even providing *any* specific highlighting instructions:

```
syn keyword clangGroupAttributes ?? GN GA GV GL GP GR PV PN SI CN
```

Why would it only evaluate certain lines of the syn keyword mapping?

Additionally, none of my regex matching worked at all despite using something as simple as `"\d\+"`.

Comment: Could you try removing the two question marks?

Comment: Since this question got only 15 views so far, maybe you want to try asking it at https://vi.stackexchange.com/?